How can I find all equivalent swapping of some edges in a graph?
This is related to electrical networks, so let me explain a bit about it first.
Assume that I have a branch or a loop consisting of only voltage sources in series, as shown below.

We know that if we swap the positions of these voltage sources, it does not change the properties of the circuit. Therefore, with branch (1), we know that we can swap all these voltage sources to get all 6 equivalent branches, as shown below.

Now, branch (1) can be modeled by a graph like this:
graph1 = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6}];

I want to find all equivalent branches that can be formed by exchanging the positions of these voltage sources. The second equivalent branch (2) would be:
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}];

and similarly for the remaining branches.
In a branch with n elements, we have
n! ways to exchange their positions. However, in a loop with n elements, we only have (n−1)! ways to exchange positions. So, in a loop with only 3 elements, there are only two ways to exchange positions like this:

So, from
graph2 = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 1}];

I want it to return two equivalent graphs.

I don't understand your semantics for "swap". In graph1, it doesn't look to me like you swapped anything. Instead it looks to me like you deleted the edge B1-A2 and added the edge A1-B2. Can you be more clear about what "swapping" actually means?

I agree with lericr. If you cannot explain the meaning of "swap" clearly in words, then give us more complicated example graphs so that we can guess what you really want to do.

@lericr Would it be better now?

@A.Kato I just edited almost everything.

yes, it's much clearer now.

@internet Yeah, it's much clearer. To be sure,  your graph must be bipartite:  "+" vertices (even integer labeled) must be connected to "-" vertices (odd integer labeled), and vice versa. Am I correct?

What is not clear to me is that you want "all swappings" ONLY for the two graphs (linear/loop)? Or, you want to solve the same problem for other (possibly more complicated) graph?

@A.Kato I want a general one for all other but can classify into two types a branch or one loop like that.

Does the general case you want correspond to labeling a graph's vertices V1, V2, ... and then asking for all non-isomorphic graphs from permutations of the labels to the vertices?

@tad I think they're isomorphic graphs, they exchaning postions of volage sources. azerbajdzan's updated version do the job, I think.

This works for the two examples.
PathGraph[#, VertexLabels -> Automatic] & /@ 
  Flatten /@ Permutations[Partition[Range[6], 2]];
DeleteDuplicatesBy[%, Sort@*EdgeList]

PathGraph[#, 
    VertexLabels -> 
     Automatic] & /@ (Append[#, First@#] & /@ (Flatten /@ 
      Permutations[Partition[Range[6], 2]]));
DeleteDuplicatesBy[%, Sort@*EdgeList]



Update after OP comment:
We use tags for each edge ("w" for wire and "V" for source) as in the original OP graph there is not enough information in the graph which tells us what is a wire and what a source.
gr = Graph[{UndirectedEdge[1, 2, "V"], UndirectedEdge[2, 3, "w"], 
   UndirectedEdge[3, 4, "V"], UndirectedEdge[4, 5, "w"], 
   UndirectedEdge[5, 6, "V"]}, VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeTag", ImageSize -> Small]
el = EdgeList[gr];
perm = Flatten /@ 
   Permutations[Cases[el, UndirectedEdge[x_, y_, "V"] -> {x, y}]];
DeleteDuplicatesBy[
 Graph[#, VertexLabels -> Automatic, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeTag", 
    ImageSize -> Small] & /@ (el /. Thread[%[[1]] -> #] & /@ perm), 
 Sort@*EdgeList]



gr = Graph[{UndirectedEdge[1, 2, "V"], UndirectedEdge[2, 3, "w"], 
   UndirectedEdge[3, 4, "V"], UndirectedEdge[4, 5, "w"], 
   UndirectedEdge[5, 6, "V"], UndirectedEdge[6, 1, "w"]}, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeTag", 
  ImageSize -> Small]
el = EdgeList[gr];
perm = Flatten /@ 
   Permutations[Cases[el, UndirectedEdge[x_, y_, "V"] -> {x, y}]];
DeleteDuplicatesBy[
 Graph[#, VertexLabels -> Automatic, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeTag", 
    ImageSize -> Small] & /@ (el /. Thread[%[[1]] -> #] & /@ perm), 
 Sort@*EdgeList]




Thanks, but this is a bit different from what I'm trying to do. My goal is generate all equivalent graphs from a given graph. So if I was given the first graph in your results above, I want to generate all other graphs.

@internet All the graphs are created from the first one. Your graphs have no information what is a wire and what is a source so I updated my answer.

The updated version works.

I'm not sure how you "spin up" your representations. Like, maybe you want simple, single-edge graphs for each voltage source and then you want to work with those graphs. But since it seemed to be easier to start with a list of unique labels, that's what I did.
sourceCount = 3;
pairedLabels = Partition[Range[2  sourceCount], 2]
(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} *)

Now you can take permutations of those pairs.
freePerms = Permutations[pairedLabels]
(* 
  {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, 
   {{1, 2}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}}, 
   {{3, 4}, {1, 2}, {5, 6}}, 
   {{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {1, 2}}, 
   {{5, 6}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 
   {{5, 6}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}}}
 *)

loopPerms = Map[Prepend[First@pairedLabels], Permutations[Rest@pairedLabels]]
(*
  {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}}}
 *)

And now you can make graphs.
(* Non-loop graphs *)
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[Flatten[#], 2, 1], VertexLabels -> "Name"] & /@ freePerms

(* Loop graphs *)
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[Flatten[#], 2, 1, {1, 1}], VertexLabels -> "Name"] & /@ loopPerms


Thanks, I think your result is a bit different from azerbajdzan that you create all permutations for edges which are not the parts of "voltage sources" as in loop.
